# Probability for drawing 2 different balls from 2 boxes

Tags: probability

Assume that we have 2 boxes with $n$ balls in each box. The balls can have different colors, where the frequency of a ball with color $a$ in box $1$ is given as $p_{1a}$. Moreover, there may be colors that are not represented in both boxes but only in 1 box. The good thing is, I know all $p_{1.}$ and $p_{2.}$ and thus, which colors are represented in each box.

Example:

```
box     1     2
---------------
red   0.1   0.2
blue  0.5   0.8
gray  0.4   0.0
```

My question is now how I can calculate the probability for drawing different-colored balls after taking $1$ ball from each box.

Is it just $$P(draw1 \neq draw2) = 1 - \sum_{i=0}^n (p_{1i} \times p_{2i})$$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The event you describe is the complement of the event of drawing same colored balls, which is comprised of $n$ disjoint events of drawing to balls of a given color for all $n$ colors. Thus $$P(\text{draw}1 \neq \text{draw}2) =1 -\sum_{i=0}^N p_{1i}p_{2i}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your confirmation!